# Angular 2 with babel ES2015 not loading and no error

Tags: javascript, angular, gruntjs, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to use angular 2 with babel, grunt, browserify and ES2015 sources. I'm trying a very basic example of simply loading a component with its template into my document.

The build run fine and the bundle is created with no error but when loaded nothing happens and I get no error in the console making it hard to debug.

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and based from examples I could find online my configuration seemed ok but if it doesn't work clearly I got something wrong. I simply cannot see it.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-es2015-babel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "angular2-es2015-babel",
  "devDependencies": {

    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.6.0",

    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "0.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd": "6.8.0",

    "grunt": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-babel": "6.0.0",
    "grunt-browserify": "4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",

    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "scripts": {

    "prestart": "npm install && grunt",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor.conf.js"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var tasks = ["babel", "browserify"];

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        babel: {
            options: {
                presets: ["es2015", "angular2"],
                plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
            },
            demo: {
                files: {
                    "app.babel.js": "app.js"
                }
            }
        },
        browserify: {
            demo: {
                files: {
                    "bundle.js": [
                        "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js",
                        "node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
                        "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
                        "node_modules/@angular/*/bundles/*.umd.js",
                        "app.babel.js"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-browserify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-babel");

    grunt.registerTask("default", tasks);
};
```

**app.js**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<p>It works!</p>"
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing to make this simple demo run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your Angular 2 application work you need to bootstrap your Angular app component.

**Code**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; //added import

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<p>It works!</p>"
})

export class AppComponent {

}

bootstrap(AppComponent); //bootstrap application here
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It works now :) I did try bootstrap but was getting an undefined error as forgot to import it!