# Update view and value in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Hi i just started using ionic 2 for my project , how to update ui value in ionic 2? jus simply when we click button some text changed. I tried this but didnt work

**home.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  public test: any;
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
  }

  update(){
    this.test = "updated text";
  }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <p>{{test}}</p>
    <button (click)="update()">update</button>
</ion-content>
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On HTML you should use `{{test}}` as you are modifying `test` varaible value.

```
<ion-content>
    <p>{{test}}</p>
    <button (click)="update()">update</button>
</ion-content>
```

---

The possibility is, you might have missed to `bootstrap` you application main component, you can see similar kind of [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37865166/2435473)

Comment: sorry , just typo.. yes already use test as variables but still didnt work. any idea?

Comment: @BijakAntusiasSufi might be you missed to bootstrap your applicaiton component. look at the updated answer, Thanks :)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer . This is for angular 2, but i don't know to apply this on ionic 2

Comment: Instead of `@Component` make it `@Page`/`@App`

Answer (score 0):

change your **home.html** to this

```
<ion-content>
<p>[(ngModel)]="test"</p>
<button (click)="update()">update</button>
```